# how to grep with color (--color=always) except when redirecting the output to a file

Tags: linux, zsh, grep

Is there a trick (probably a `zsh` function) to make a **single** `grep` command behave this way?

1. if `grep` output is written to the terminal, or is piped to another command (usually `less -R`) -> use color
2. if `grep` output is written to a file -> don't use color

The problem with `grep --color=always` is that it behaves incorrectly in case 2.

EDIT - Let's put it another way:

- I need `mygrep "a" file.txt | less -R` to output colors.
- I need `mygrep "a" file.txt > output.txt` to output NO colors.

How should `mygrep` be defined in my `.zshrc`?

---

Comment: Probably I don't understand your question... but `grep --color` seems to do what you want, except if you pipe the output it will be colorless.

Comment: `grep --color=auto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Kubuntu `[ -f /dev/stdout ]` can be used to tell if stdout is a regular file. This leads to the following shell function:

```sh
mygrep() {
   if [ -f /dev/stdout ]; then
      grep --color=never "$@"
   else
      grep --color=always "$@"
   fi
}
```

There's nothing specific to `zsh` here. The question is tagged [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), the function should work in Linux. In general (in other systems) [experiences with `/dev/stdout` may vary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36403/108618).